# how to insert data from list into excel in python

Tags: python

how to insert data from list into excel in python
for example i exported this data from log file :

```
data= ["101","am1","123450","2015-01-01 11:19:00","test1 test1".....]
      ["102","am2","123451","2015-01-01 11:20:00","test2 test3".....]
      ["103","am3","123452","2015-01-01 11:21:00","test3 test3".....]
```

Output result:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uTOE.png

.

Comment: You can use Pandas module to export data as `.xlsx`

Answer (score 1):

The module pandas has a `DataFrame.to_excel()` function that would do that.

```
import pandas as pd

data= [["101","am1","123450","2015-01-01 11:19:00","test1 test1"],
      ["102","am2","123451","2015-01-01 11:20:00","test2 test3"],
      ["103","am3","123452","2015-01-01 11:21:00","test3 test3"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel('my_data.xmls')
```

That should do it.